# Does IPsec anti replay service also takes care related to reordering of packets?

Tags: networking, ipsec

I am working for a anti replay window service for my project and while going through the document I can see that window size is maintained i.e top and bottom, could someone please help me in understanding that sequence number here has anything to do with ordering of packets, my understanding is any packet within the window range the receiver gets, it check(section A2.2. of RFC 4303:), does the integrity check and if it valid mark the index and fwd. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question as it doesn't really have anything to do with programming (maybe security.stackexchange.com fits better as it's related to IPsec, but this might be a tricky one as there does not seem to be a site to discuss network protocols in general). But to quickly answer your main question: no, IPsec packets are not reordered by sequence numbers; like IP, IPsec does not provide ordering of packets.

Comment: Thanks ,I have one more query over the anti replay window service, considering one example.
I am having a 64 window size, window size range from 1 to 64.
Considering all sequence no received by the receiver except seq no 3,  later received seq no 68 and the top window shifted to 4 bits and bottom window to 4 bit right. 
Top= 68 Bottom= 5
So now in this case, the first question is:
1. Whether the window will shift 4 bit?
2. If yes what will happen for seq no 3 index  which is not received. Later If seq no 3 gets in then seq no < bottom so packet should dropped right? Could you plz clarify